# How can I prevent Eclipse from automatically switching and creating Run and Debug Configurations?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, configuration, program-entry-point

If I have a Run or Debug configuration working in Eclipse, and I click on a different file in the same project, and that file happens to contains a "main" function, and then click Run or Debug, Eclipse will automatically assume that I want to run that particular file, and if no configuration exists for that run, it will create one and switch to it.

Is there a way for me to prevent this - i.e. force Eclipse to always use a selected Run or Debug configuration, no matter what the active file is when I click Run. That would be very good and would significantly enhance my efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching allows you to configure this.

[image: launch configuration]

You probably want the "Always launch the previously launched application".

(Note:  This is Neon on MacOS - might be slightly different for you)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been staring so much at this, and I can't believe I didn't find this.

Comment: They changed it from your desired behavior to this many versions back, but added this for exactly this reason.  Have fun :)